# Error updating MySQL data through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I try to update the data making use of checkboxes. But when one or more of the checkboxes is not checked, a notice is returned:

Notice: Undefined index: stats2 in E:\wamp\www\HOSPITAL\update.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: stats3 in E:\wamp\www\HOSPITAL\update.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: stats5 in E:\wamp\www\HOSPITAL\update.php on line 12

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("Hospital", $con);




       mysql_query("UPDATE t2 SET HOSPNUM ='$_POST[hnum]', ROOMNUM='$_POST[rnum]', ADDATE= '$_POST[ad8]', ADTIME='$_POST[adtym]', LASTNAME='$_POST[lname]', FIRSTNAME='$_POST[fname]', MIDNAME='$_POST[mname]', CSTAT='$_POST[cs]', AGE='$_POST[age]', BDAY='$_POST[bday]', ADDRESS='$_POST[ad]', SEX='$_POST[sex]', 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               STAT='$_POST[stats1]', STAT2='$_POST[stats2]', STAT3='$_POST[stats3]', STAT4='$_POST[stats4]', STAT5='$_POST[stats5]', STAT6='$_POST[stats6]', STAT7='$_POST[stats8]', STAT8='$_POST[stats8]', NURSE='$_POST[nurse]'              
        WHERE TELNUM ='$_POST[telnum]'");



    mysql_close($con)
    ?>
```

Could you help me, so that the notice would not show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the defined behavoir for checkboxes - only when set are they included in the form data.

You should use isset() to determine if the checkbox is ticked.

change it to

```
STAT='".isset($_POST['stats1']).", 
STAT2='".isset($_POST['stats2']).", 
STAT3='".isset($_POST['stats3']).", 
STAT4='".isset($_POST['stats4']).",  
STAT5='".isset($_POST['stats5']).", 
STAT6='".isset($_POST['stats6']).", 
STAT7='".isset($_POST['stats8']).", 
STAT8='".isset($_POST['stats8'])."
```

Another workaround which works is to add a hidden variable, with the same name, before the checkbox: e.g.

```
<form action='t1.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name="cb1" value="0">
<input type='checkbox' name="cb1" title='test'>
<input type='submit'  >
</form>
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: thanks, this trick works. I really could learn some good techniques in here

Answer (score 1):

The `$_POST` array doesn't contain a `stats2` index. This is because when a checkbox is not checked it will not be included in the post request.

If the form elements are static then you can just check to see if they are set:
Replace `STAT6='$_POST[stats6]'` with `STAT6=(array_key_exists('stats6', $_POST))`.

If the form elements are generated dynamically, eg:

```
foreach($students as $student)
{ 
    echo "<input element='checkbox' name='student-is-present-{$value}'>";
}
```

then include a hidden element in the form so that you can determine what's checked and what's not checked:

```
foreach($students as $student)
{ 
    echo "<input element='hidden' name='student-{$value}' value='student-is-present-{$value}'>";
    echo "<input element='checkbox' name='student-is-present-{$value}'>";
}
```

You should quote the array keys. Eg use `$_POST['stats5']` instead of `$_POST[stats5]`. Your SQL is open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection) too. To avoid this you should escape the data with a function like `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a checkbox on a form its value is only sent to the server if the box is ticked.  If it is not ticked then that key won't exist in the $_POST array, hence the errors you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You should also sanitize the input with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://uk.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to prevent mysql injection.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use POST and GET variables directly in your array. you should clean them, search for mysql injection to find out more :

```
$hnum = isset($_POST['hnum']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hnum']) : '';
```

and then use those variables. This way you avoid mysql injection and resolve those notices